# Setting SVG Object Dimensions via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

A very basic SVG/JavaScript question: How do you set the width and height of an SVG object (polygon, path, ellipse, etc.) via JavaScript?

This is my first interactive SVG after years of working in ActionScript. I'm just trying to set the height of bars in a bar chart dynamically. I've gotten quite a ways into this project setting fill color and visibility of various objects with pedestrian code like this:

```
targetbar=document.getElementById("rep"+loopcount);
targetbar.setAttribute("visibility", "visible");
```

But plugging `height` and a number into the `setAttribute` command does not work, nor has anything else I've copied from various code snippets found online.

Thinking that I'd keep this first project as plain-vanilla as possible, I haven't been using any external libraries. At least for now I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve JQuery, Raphael, D3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most elements in SVG simply don't have height and width attributes. Polygons have the set of coordinates of the vertices, paths have co-ordinates of the various path objects and ellipses have the semi-major and semi-minor axis radii.

You can scale a shape by setting a transform attribute on it which will adjust the width and height proportionally e.g. transform="scale(1.1, 0.9)" would make any shape slightly wider and less tall than it normally was.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I had looked at the transform command, but it appears to be code that belongs in the SVG XML, not in the JavaScript. I need to size the bars to varying heights as the user interacts with the SVG, and I don't see how that would work being in the XML. In ActionScript this would look something like:

function updatebaron (Release){
play();
}

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "not in the JavaScript" javascript can alter the DOM to set/edit/remove the transform if that's what you need. Just call setAttribute or removeAttribute as appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I posted that comment prematurely, but I think you got at the answer anyway.

I've been keeping all the code that actually does anything outside the XML in a <script> section and calling it with "onmouseover", etc., so I wasn't sure what to do with code that looked like it was part of the XML.

Comment: But based on your last comment I did some searching and I found this:

<g
onmouseover="this.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(2)');
this.style.fill='#83b901';
>

I'll still probably call a separate function containing a setAttribute() command from an onmousedown line in the XML, but I think that gets me over the conceptual hurdle I had. Thanks.